# C makefile with different directories

Tags: c, makefile

I'm currently trying to get understand makefiles. I've read a few tutorials and also had a look into the [`GNU Make Manual`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/). But I still don't get it how I solve my problem.

I've got the following structure:

```
makefile
main.c
|_ test
   |_ hello.c
   |_ hello.h
```

In the test folder, there is a C file with a method I'd like to use in the main.

---

**My makefile looks like this**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Itest/

# Include dir
INC = test

# Messing around with sources to get the file paths
_SRC = hallo.c
tmp  = $(patsubst %, $(INC)/%, $(_SRC))
SRC = main.c
SRC += $(tmp)

# output
$(info $$var is [${SRC}])

_DEPS = hello.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %, $(INC)/%, $(_DEPS))

ODIR = obj
_OBJ = main.o hello.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %, $(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

# Not sure if the $(DEPS) does anything here
$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SRC)  $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

build : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)


.PHONY: clean

clean :
    -rm *.o
    -rm $(ODIR)/*.o
    rm build
```

I've added some comments there so you can understand what I tried to do. I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me what I did in a bad way.

---

**My problem is here**

```
# Not sure if the $(DEPS) does anything here
$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SRC)  $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

I know that the **$<** takes the first argument from **$(SRC)** but that isn't what I need. But I somehow miss how to use one entry after the other.

Another thing I do not get yet is that **$(DEPS)**. There is no difference if the `DEPS` are there or not (as far as I can tell from my newbie perspective).

Please share your wisdom.

Comment: `$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SRC)  $(DEPS)` -> `$(ODIR)/%.o : %.c  $(DEPS)`

Comment: How are you executing this Makefile? (ie what command are you running)

Comment: The mind set of a make file is very different to a script. It is almost backwards. You create rules and dependencies so you start at the result and everything need for that result is built. Do NOT start with "what shall I do first". So you need a list of objects to make an executable, and you need a general rule to make the object. The object comes from the source using the suggested above, $(ODIR)/%.o : %.c $(DEPS)  Which tells the make file how to build any object from the source with the same name.

Comment: So i don't think you need to list the source files. It is driven by the list of objects. As a first step, removing the source list may help things be clearer. Create a list of objects, later you can try to construct the list of objects from a list of source, or from the directory content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're working too hard.  Let's start with stating what you want make to do for you, and then think about how to generalize it.

```
# it seems Test.Dir is an include directory
TEST.DIR = test

# use modern C
CC = gcc -std=c11
# make gdb more convenient to use, and supply an include directory
CFLAGS = -g -O0 -I$(TEST.DIR)

# the main output is "main"
# it depends on main.c and hello.c
# let make compile .c to .o on its own, using built-in rules, if that's enough

main: main.o $(TEST.DIR)/hello.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^

# remind make that hello.o also depends on hello.h
$(TEST.DIR)/hello.o: $(TEST.DIR)/hello.h

# is it also true that main.c includes hello.h?  
# then say so, else you don't need the -I option

main.o: $(TEST.DIR)/hello.h
```

There are a couple of ways to generate include-file dependencies.  I myself use mkdep; it's also possible to use gcc for the same purpose.

The pattern substitution functions are powerful, but error-prone.  Try to keep things as simple as possible, and introduce functions only where they will capture patterns, to save you typing (and potentially introduce errors in so doing).